# Facebook Login - Fatal error at userEmail

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, facebook-login

I'm about to teach myself swift and it's going pretty well. 
BUT! Always a but...

I have implemented the Facebook Login Button on my app at the start page. It works fine the first time when I tap the login. It changes the scene after the login, so I can continue, but if I then quit the simulator and opens the app again, it gives me this error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The error is found at:

```
let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
```

The app autologin when the user has logged in one time before, so they can avoid logging in all the time, but it seems like it wont save the userEmail? It finds the users name, but it can't find the email. I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to get a clear answer on how this can be. 
I hope I have clarified myself and it's understandable!

Regards
Alexander

Edit:

```
func returnUserData() {
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in                
        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            println("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}
```

My function looks like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is asynchronous make sure result/result's data is not null or request is finished before calling methods on it!
Very important: variables get cleared between launches. Use NSUserDefaults for saving variables between launches.
If you are using core data you probably forgot to do this:

```
func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(userName, forKey: "USERNAME")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(userEmail, forKey: "EMAIL")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: var email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("email")! as! String . ... Like that?

Comment: Yes, you can use the ones specific for String objects or these functions :  func setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey defaultName: String)  and func objectForKey(defaultName: String) -> AnyObject?                               Please don't forget to upvote! :)

Comment: I'm upvoting! :-) But should I just add those two functions?

Comment: Yes, you need to store in  NSUserDefaults before you can get from it! thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. I did what you said, and the fatal error keeps popping :-/

Comment: It did, in some way. Now I get the output: User Email is: nil. So somewhere, I believe it is the error thing, I have made a mistake. Hmm.. What could this be? I'm can't really see a solution right now :D